# Create Script of database with SQL query

Tags: sql, sql-server, backup

I have purchased space online on godaddy on which my SQL database is stored but now I want to copy that database to my local pc but I cannot take backup of SQL database as it is giving error at taking backup and I cannot create a script too. So, anybody have any idea how to create script of database with SQL query?

> Error : Index was out of bound array

Comment: What error are you getting?

Comment: error is index was out of bound array

Comment: What kind of database engine do you use?

Answer (score 0):

```
USE databasename;
GO
BACKUP DATABASE databasename
TO DISK = 'C:\SQLServerBackups\databasename.Bak'
   WITH FORMAT,
      MEDIANAME = 'C_SQLServerBackups',
      NAME = 'Full Backup of databasename';
GO
```

Comment: sir i dont want it to disk becuase i dont have server online i have just sql so i want query that generates a script of database

Comment: So you want a query that would recreate all tables and structure?

Comment: exactly as my task -> create script is not working and giving error (index was out of bound array)

Comment: Hmmm this may be more than 1 script to do this? Someone more intelligent that I will probably answer before me but i shall have a go! In the mean time post up what you tried in your question so it doesn't get down voted into oblivion.

Comment: cant write anything as every solution is telling to save database to disk not creating a script

Answer (score 0):

login in Godaddy-> select and launch your host- > select database->options -> backup

here you can see where it will take. then open file manager, move to that location, download .bak file

Comment: problem is also at the website login as it is not allowing me to log in it